Amazon Pinpoint C# SDK
I am trying to use the C# AWS SDK to create Pinpoint Segments and Journey.
When I execute with the Journey status as ACTIVE, it creates, but it doesn't get the contacts from the Segment.
Segment without contacts:

If I try to create it manually, it works fine, only by using the code it doesn't do everything.
My C# .netFramework 4.8 code:
public ActionResult CreateSegment()
{
    Amazon.RegionEndpoint region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
    string bucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BucketName"];
    string accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];
    string secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"];
    var pinpointAppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PinPointAppId"];
    
    // Pinpoint client and segment definition logic
    var pinpointClient = new Amazon.Pinpoint.AmazonPinpointClient(accessKey, secretKey, region);
    
    var segmentName = "Segment_wa_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
    var journeyName = "Journey_wa_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
    
    // Define the import job details
    var importJobRequest = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.CreateImportJobRequest
    {
        ApplicationId = pinpointAppId,
        ImportJobRequest = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.ImportJobRequest
        {
            DefineSegment = true,  
            Format = Amazon.Pinpoint.Format.CSV,
            RegisterEndpoints = true,
            RoleArn = "ROLE_ARN", 
            S3Url = $"s3://amazon-pinpoint-segment-files/Staging/Pinpoint-WallaceTest.csv",
            SegmentName = segmentName
        }
    };
    
    // Create the import job
    var createImportJobResponse = pinpointClient.CreateImportJobAsync(importJobRequest).Result;
    
    // Check for successful import job creation
    if (createImportJobResponse.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || createImportJobResponse.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        if (createImportJobResponse.ImportJobResponse != null && createImportJobResponse.ImportJobResponse.Definition != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Import job created successfully. Job ID: " + createImportJobResponse.ImportJobResponse.Id);
            var segmentId = createImportJobResponse.ImportJobResponse.Definition.SegmentId;
    
            // Check the Segment Jobs status
            var getImportRequest = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.GetImportJobRequest()
            {
                ApplicationId = pinpointAppId,
                JobId = createImportJobResponse.ImportJobResponse.Id
            };
    
            var numberOfTries = 100;
            var count = 0;
            var jobSuccess = false;
            while (!jobSuccess)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (count > numberOfTries)
                        break;
    
                    var segmentResponse = pinpointClient.GetImportJob(getImportRequest);
                    count++;
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    
                    if (segmentResponse.ImportJobResponse != null)
                    {
                        if (segmentResponse.ImportJobResponse.JobStatus == Amazon.Pinpoint.JobStatus.COMPLETED)
                        {
                            jobSuccess = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (segmentResponse.ImportJobResponse.JobStatus == Amazon.Pinpoint.JobStatus.FAILING ||
                            segmentResponse.ImportJobResponse.JobStatus == Amazon.Pinpoint.JobStatus.FAILED)
                        {
                            jobSuccess = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }
            }
    
            if (jobSuccess)
            {
                Dictionary<string, Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.Activity> activities = new Dictionary<string, Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.Activity>();
    
                // Define the journey activities
                activities.Add("ConnectCall", new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.Activity()
                {
                    ContactCenter = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.ContactCenterActivity() { }
                });
    
                // Define the journey definition
                var createJourneyRequest = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.CreateJourneyRequest
                {
                    ApplicationId = pinpointAppId,
                    WriteJourneyRequest = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.WriteJourneyRequest()
                    {
                        Name = journeyName,
                        Schedule = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.JourneySchedule()
                        {
                            StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2),
                            EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(12),
                            Timezone = "UTC-07"
                        },
                        StartCondition = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.StartCondition
                        {
                            SegmentStartCondition = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.SegmentCondition
                            {
                                SegmentId = segmentId
                            }
                        },
                        State = Amazon.Pinpoint.State.ACTIVE,
                        JourneyChannelSettings = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.JourneyChannelSettings
                        {
                            ConnectCampaignArn = "AMAZON_CONNECT_CAMPAIGN_ARN",
                            ConnectCampaignExecutionRoleArn = "ROLE_ARN"
                        },
                        StartActivity = "ConnectCall",
                        LocalTime = true,
                        Activities = activities,
                        RefreshOnSegmentUpdate = false
                    }
                };
    
                // Create the journey
                var journey = pinpointClient.CreateJourney(createJourneyRequest);
    
                if (journey.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || journey.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                {
                    // Future logic
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error creating import job: " + createImportJobResponse.HttpStatusCode);
    }
}

Thank you.
I'm trying to create an Amazon Connect Segment and Journey automatically to make Voice calls using Amazon Connect.
Edit: After a few seconds, the message "Segment no longer exists" disappears and the list shows there, but it doesn't bring any entries.

Does it help if you fiddle around with the sleep timer , this definitely looks a timing issue.

You were right about the timing, even showing the message "Segment no longer exists", after a few seconds it updates and shows the segment list.
My problem now is that the Journey segment is empty

Problem solved after adding  SendingSchedule = false, TimezoneEstimationMethods = new List { } and changing the LocalTime to false on the WriteJourneyRequest.

After contact with Amazon, I was informed that the segment without contacts is a visual problem and it was not the problem affecting the calls.
They encouraged me to use the AWS CLI to check the Journeys and then I noticed something missing in the code, following the updated code that works to make calls through Amazon Connect.
public ActionResult CreateSegment()
{
    Amazon.RegionEndpoint region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
    var segmentId = "";
    var jobSuccess = false;
    string bucketName = "amazon-pinpoint-segment-files";
    string accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];
    string secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"];
    var connectCampaignArn = "CONNECT_CAMP_ARN_HERE";
    var connectCampaignExecutionRoleArn = "CONNECT_EXECUTION_ROLE";
    var pinpointAppId = "PINPOINT_APP_ID";
    var segmentName = "Segment_wa_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
    var journeyName = "Journey_wa_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
    var offset = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.Hours.ToString("00");

    // Pinpoint client and segment definition logic
    using (var pinpointClient = new Amazon.Pinpoint.AmazonPinpointClient(accessKey, secretKey, region))
    {
        // Define the import job details
        var importJobRequest = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.CreateImportJobRequest
        {
            ApplicationId = pinpointAppId,
            ImportJobRequest = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.ImportJobRequest
            {
                DefineSegment = true,
                Format = Amazon.Pinpoint.Format.CSV,
                RegisterEndpoints = true,
                RoleArn = "ROLE_ARN",
                S3Url = $"s3://{bucketName}/Staging/Pinpoint-WallaceTest1.csv",
                SegmentName = segmentName
            }
        };

        // Create the import job
        var createImportJobResponse = pinpointClient.CreateImportJobAsync(importJobRequest).Result;

        // Check for successful import job creation
        if (createImportJobResponse.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || createImportJobResponse.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
            if (createImportJobResponse.ImportJobResponse != null && createImportJobResponse.ImportJobResponse.Definition != null)
            {
                segmentId = createImportJobResponse.ImportJobResponse.Definition.SegmentId;

                // Check the Segment Jobs status
                var getImportRequest = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.GetImportJobRequest()
                {
                    ApplicationId = pinpointAppId,
                    JobId = createImportJobResponse.ImportJobResponse.Id
                };

                var numberOfTries = 100;
                var count = 0;
                while (!jobSuccess)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (count > numberOfTries)
                            break;

                        var segmentResponse = pinpointClient.GetImportJob(getImportRequest);

                        if (segmentResponse.ImportJobResponse != null)
                        {
                            if (segmentResponse.ImportJobResponse.JobStatus == Amazon.Pinpoint.JobStatus.COMPLETED)
                            {
                                jobSuccess = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (segmentResponse.ImportJobResponse.JobStatus == Amazon.Pinpoint.JobStatus.FAILING ||
                                segmentResponse.ImportJobResponse.JobStatus == Amazon.Pinpoint.JobStatus.FAILED)
                            {
                                jobSuccess = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        count++;
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    { }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error creating import job: " + createImportJobResponse.HttpStatusCode);
            }
        }
    }

    if (jobSuccess && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(segmentId))
    {
        using (var pinpointClient = new Amazon.Pinpoint.AmazonPinpointClient(accessKey, secretKey, region))
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Dictionary<string, Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.Activity> activities = new Dictionary<string, Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.Activity>();

            // Define the journey activities
            activities.Add("ConnectCall", new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.Activity()
            {
                ContactCenter = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.ContactCenterActivity() { }
            });

            // Define the journey definition
            var createJourneyRequest = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.CreateJourneyRequest
            {
                ApplicationId = pinpointAppId,
                WriteJourneyRequest = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.WriteJourneyRequest()
                {
                    Name = journeyName,
                    Schedule = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.JourneySchedule()
                    {
                        StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2),
                        EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(12),
                        Timezone = $"UTC{offset}"
                    },
                    StartCondition = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.StartCondition
                    {
                        SegmentStartCondition = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.SegmentCondition
                        {
                            SegmentId = segmentId
                        }
                    },
                    State = Amazon.Pinpoint.State.ACTIVE,
                    JourneyChannelSettings = new Amazon.Pinpoint.Model.JourneyChannelSettings
                    {
                        ConnectCampaignArn = connectCampaignArn,
                        ConnectCampaignExecutionRoleArn = connectCampaignExecutionRoleArn
                    },
                    StartActivity = "ConnectCall",
                    SendingSchedule = false,
                    LocalTime = false,
                    Activities = activities,
                    RefreshOnSegmentUpdate = false,
                    TimezoneEstimationMethods = new List<string> { }
                }
            };

            // Create the journey
            var journey = pinpointClient.CreateJourney(createJourneyRequest);

            if (journey.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || journey.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                // Future logic
            }
        }
    }

    return Content($"");
}

I was missing the:

SendingSchedule = false;
Change the LocalTime to false
TimezoneEstimationMethods = new List { }

